# Merge multiple workbooks in one (new) master workbook using C#

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I need some help on integrating multiple workbooks into a single master workbook. I am trying to use the following code. I would really appreciate if someone could please help me with following problems:

1. saving the final (master) workbook having all the worksheets
2. the worksheets in different workbooks should not loose formatting while copying to master workbook.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.IO;

namespace IntegrationMacro
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
            app.Visible = true;
            app.Workbooks.Add("");
            app.Workbooks.Add(@"C:\Users\ssehgal\Documents\Excel-Files-For-Macro\WorkBook1.xls");
            app.Workbooks.Add(@"C:\Users\ssehgal\Documents\Excel-Files-For-Macro\WorkBook2.xls");
            for (int i = 2; i <= app.Workbooks.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= app.Workbooks[i].Worksheets.Count; j++)
                {
                    Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)app.Workbooks[i].Worksheets[j];
                    ws.Copy(app.Workbooks[1].Worksheets[1]);                    
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = new Application() { Visible = true };
var master = app.Workbooks.Add();

// repeat this for each workbook you need to combine...
app.Workbooks.Add(__PATH_TO_THE_WORKBOOK__)
    .Worksheets.Cast<Worksheet>()
    .ToList() // Move() will modify the source of enumeration, so we need to make a temp copy
    .ForEach(x => x.Move(master.Sheets[1]));
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. The code worked.. However, I am not able to save the formatting of the header like color. Is there any way to save the header color too?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce that. Both column header and page header copied fine for me on Excel2010. Can you provide a sample file to reproduce the problem?